# why ScheduledExecutorService has shutdown in 15th second, but it will still execute 17th and 20th second task?

Tags: java, threadpool

this is the code:

```
public class TimerTask {
  private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;
  private ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture;

  TimerTask() {
    scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
  }

  private void startTimerTask() {
    Runnable printTask = createPrintTask();
    System.out.println(new Date());
    scheduledFuture = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(printTask, 5, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    scheduler.schedule(() -> {
      if (scheduledFuture != null && !scheduledFuture.isCancelled()) {
        scheduledFuture.cancel(true);
        System.out.println(new Date());
      }
    }, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    scheduler.schedule(() -> {
      if (scheduledFuture != null || scheduledFuture.isCancelled()) {
        System.out.println(scheduledFuture.isDone() + "  " + scheduledFuture.isCancelled());
        scheduler.shutdown();
      }
    }, 15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    scheduler.schedule(() -> {
      if (scheduledFuture != null || scheduledFuture.isCancelled()) {
        System.out.println("danluo");
      }
    }, 17, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    scheduledFuture = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(printTask, 20, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  private Runnable createPrintTask() {
    return () -> System.out.println("nsnnsn" + new Date());
  }

  public static void main(String []args) {
    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask();
    timerTask.startTimerTask();
  }

}
```

this is the output:

```
Wed May 24 10:39:06 CST 2017
nsnnsnWed May 24 10:39:11 CST 2017
nsnnsnWed May 24 10:39:13 CST 2017
nsnnsnWed May 24 10:39:15 CST 2017
Wed May 24 10:39:16 CST 2017
nsnnsnWed May 24 10:39:17 CST 2017
nsnnsnWed May 24 10:39:19 CST 2017
nsnnsnWed May 24 10:39:21 CST 2017
true  true
danluo
```

why it will execute 20th second task before 17th second and 15th second?
it seems so strange. could you please help me to answer the question? 
thanks.

It shows that the code is too many, I don't know why, So I add some explain again.

Answer (score 0):

When you say,

```
scheduler.schedule(() -> {
  if (scheduledFuture != null || scheduledFuture.isCancelled()) {
    System.out.println("danluo");
  }
}, 17, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

you can read it like *if `scheduledFuture` is not `null` **or** it has been cancelled* which makes no logical sense. If it is `null` then the second test will throw a null pointer exception. Thus, I can only conclude you wanted

```
scheduler.schedule(() -> {
  if (scheduledFuture != null && !scheduledFuture.isCancelled()) {
    System.out.println("danluo");
  }
}, 17, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

which would read

> if `scheduledFuture` is not `null` **and** it has **not** been cancelled.

because when you have ended the task you presumably **don't** want to continue doing the task. As for the **second** `scheduledFuture` at twenty second intervals, when you say `scheduledFuture = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate` you create a new one... the jvm notes that you no longer reference the old `scheduledFuture` instance - but you have more then one, and one isn't *reachable* (to you). Use a new reference name for that. Or make a `List` or use a `PriorityQueue` if you need to schedule multiple tasks.

Answer (score 0):

answering the question from the title of your post why the scheduled tasks are executed although the ExecutorService is shutdown from the JavaDocs for `ExecutorService.shutdown()`:

> Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted. Invocation has no additional effect if already shut down.

So your scheduled task will run until they are finished and only then the ExecutorService itself will stop.